# Since updating to swift 2.0 I'm having an error with authentication code, it's telling me extra argument 'error' in call

Tags: ios, swift

```
var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error:&responseError)

        if ( urlData != nil) {
            let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

            if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
            { var responseData:NSString = NSString(data: urlData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);
```

Comment: Do you see the list of related question on the right side? They tell me you **did absolutely nothing** on your own to figure out what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2):

actually `NSError` is removed in `Swift2.0 and above`

try  in this place

```
var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error:&responseError)
```

use this

```
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)
```

**Update**

> sendSynchronousRequest is deprecated in iOS 9 , in this place use `dataTaskWithRequest`

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url_to_request)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

    let paramString = "data=Hello"
    request.HTTPBody = paramString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    (
        let data, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(dataString)

    }

    task.resume()
```

for sample see [this](http://www.kaleidosblog.com/nsurlsession-in-swift-get-and-post-data)